# kiwix is creating a index of wikipedia even when i downloaded the portable 46 GB wikipedia which has index files already

Tags: wikipedia

I downloaded the portable version of Wikipedia the complete one.That was about 46.32 GB which includes about 11 GB of index files under `D:\kiwix\data\index\wikipedia_en_all_02_2014.zim.idx`

But when i try to search in `kiwix` it asks me to create index. Creating index will take huge time and space why doesn't it uses the already created index. I didn't install kiwix i am using the portable version.

How can I make Kiwix to use those index files?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution myself.

Just edit the `library.xml` file using notepad, present under

`C:\Users\(your account)\AppData\Roaming\www.kiwix.org\Kiwix\Profiles\<something>.default`

Add the path of the index as

`indexType="xapian" indexPath="D:\Kiwix\data\index\wikipedia_en_all_02_2014.zim.idx`

Replace with your own index file address, before title entry,which is something like

`title="Wikipedia" description="The Free Encyclopedia" language="eng" date="2014-02-21"`

and save it.